# Possible to edit typo3conf/ files without being root user?

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.1.x, realurl

I'm running typo3 v6.1

I want to configure "news system" and "realURL", in order to have nice looking URLs for my news.

I can't access my files in typo3conf/ folder, so I can't modify typo3conf/ext/news/ext_localconf.php (don't have root access)

I can't find an other way to access this file (*I looked in the install tool*)

**I would like to know if someone know an other way to edit this file, or to set up nice looking URLs for my news.**

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The RealURL configuration for the News extension must be added to your RealURL configuration file, located (most probably) in the typo3conf/ folder. If you don't have write access to this folder, you cannot change it. Ask your site admin to grant access to these files (if you are allowed to make such changes).

Documentation:
http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/Main/Administration/Realurl/Index.html

You will normally not want to edit files of extensions directly because you're losing the possibility to update the extensions. Therefore if you need to change the behaviour of an extension, use one of these ways:

- To change field configurations (make a field required etc.), overwrite the TCA in typo3conf/extTables.php.
- To change the appearance of a field (e.g. a different label for a field, preset values), use Page TypoScript Configuration.
- To change RealURL configuration, edit the global configuration (default: typoconf/realurl_conf.php)
- To add fields to an extension or alter behaviour, create an extension that extends the extension.
- To change templates/layouts, copy whole folder into ie `fileadmin/my_news_views` and change the configuration of the ext using Template module -> Constants

Comment: Thank you for answering.
Yes I can do that, my colleague have root access and can do it for me, but I just wonder if there's not an other way to do it, because I think it's really annoying to have this great ext and not be able to configure it! 
I used an other CMS before and I had access to all files and folders, so it seams normal and easier for me to have access to everything ! :)

Comment: There is no GUI for editing RealURL configuration. I added some hints about altering behaviour of extensions to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the Extension Manager you can install and use T3Quixplorer

http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/t3quixplorer

Comment: sorry for answering so late
thank you, i'll have a look... some day.
For this project, i just changed my access on the files i needed. But maybe it could be useful for an other project (i hope i will never use it again, i really didn't like typo3!!^^)